# xournal-like software on bq aquaris m10?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, annotation, stylus

Has anyone been able to use xournal-like annotator on bq aquaris m10? I just got one and this would be one of the principal reasons I'll use a tablet for--to annotate pdf documents.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for waking up an old post but I was also searching for such an app. Unfortunately, I didn't find any. I therefore used libertine to install the xournal package on my bq M10. In OTA-14, it works quite well since ubuntu touch can now run desktop apps. Yet there are few disagreable bugs when you start writing after changing color or tool.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Could you please explain how to install?

Comment: please restructure your answer so its more helpful.